# Instagram Graph API not showing values for demographics metrics

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I've been using the Instagram Graph API for my research project and I'm getting all the other information without issues but when it comes to the demographic metrics i.e `engaged_audience_demographics, reached_audience_demographics, follower_demographics`, I'm not getting the values.

Using: Django

My request body:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/"+ig_id+"/insights"
params = {
            'metric': 'engaged_audience_demographics,reached_audience_demographics,follower_demographics',
            'metric_type': 'total_value',
            'period': 'lifetime',
            'timeframe': 'last_90_days',
            'breakdowns': 'age,city,country,gender',
            'access_token': access_token,
        }
```

The response I'm getting:

```
"data": [
                {
                    "name": "engaged_audience_demographics",
                    "period": "lifetime",
                    "title": "Engaged audience demographics",
                    "description": "The demographic characteristics of the engaged audience, including countries, cities and gender distribution.",
                    "id": "<ig_id>/insights/engaged_audience_demographics/lifetime"
                },
                {
                    "name": "reached_audience_demographics",
                    "period": "lifetime",
                    "title": "Reached audience demographics",
                    "description": "The demographic characteristics of the reached audience, including countries, cities and gender distribution.",
                    "id": "<ig_id>/insights/reached_audience_demographics/lifetime"
                },
                {
                    "name": "follower_demographics",
                    "period": "lifetime",
                    "title": "Follower demographics",
                    "description": "The demographic characteristics of followers, including countries, cities and gender distribution.",
                    "id": "<ig_id>/insights/follower_demographics/lifetime"
                }
            ]
```

My account has all the demographics information needed so we can eliminate the possibility of the data being non-existent.
According to the documentation, I'm supposed to get `breakdowns` as follows:

*expected result*

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "engaged_audience_demographics",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "title": "Engaged audience demographics",
      "description": "The demographic characteristics of the engaged audience, including countries, cities and gender distribution.",
      "total_value": {
        "breakdowns": [
          {
            "dimension_keys": [
              "timeframe",
              "country"
            ],
            "results": [
              {
                "dimension_values": [
                  "LAST_90_DAYS",
                  "AR"
                ],
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "dimension_values": [
                  "LAST_90_DAYS",
                  "RU"
                ],
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "dimension_values": [
                  "LAST_90_DAYS",
                  "MA"
                ],
                "value": 1
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": "<ig_id>/insights/engaged_audience_demographics/lifetime"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong in the request because as per the documentation, everything seems right but I wonder why I'm not getting the expected result.

Can someone help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found the mistake I was making.
In the request params, it should be

```
breakdown: "age"
```

instead of

```
breakdowns: "age,city,country,gender"
```

And I have to call the API multiple times for each breakdown.